# Rubeque: The average sum of two random values

Tags: ruby, statistics

I was able to answer this [problem](http://www.rubeque.com/problems/the-limits-of-probability)

> Instructions: Try to guess the average sum of two random values.
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> random_values = (0..1000000).inject(0.0) do |sum, _| 
>   sum += rand(14) + rand(14)
> end
>
> assert_equal (random_values/1000000.0).round, ___
> ```

Looking at the other answers (around 3 pages), it's weird that the other users gave the same answer:

> 13

I thought we would have different answers since the addends are supposedly randomly generated.

Is the average being the same number a quirk specific to Ruby's random number generator or this behaviour would still appear whichever random number generator is used?

Comment: Don't just link to a question. Write the question completely by yourself. Don't be lazy. Don't put burden on the reader.

Comment: If the random variables are independently distributed, as your code suggests, the expected value of the sum equals the sum of the expected values. If, in addition, the random variables have identical distributions, which your code also suggests, it is only necessary to estimate the mean of the distribution and then multiply that by two.